# Not able to call bean method when making conditional display of include page in JSF

Tags: jsf

I have home page, dashboard page and addfield page. home page has link for dashboard and dashboard has link for add field. this is working fine when command link is clicked.
I want to show addfield page inside dash board and dashboard page in home page. when i am using include to display page it is including the page and displaying.

When I want to display dashBoard page  page on click of home command link it is not     working with

```
<f:ajax event="action" render="panelid">
```

and

```
<h:panelgroup id="panelid" rendered="#{home.showPage}">
    <h:include src="/dashboard.xhtml">
</h:panelGroup>
```

I checked while debugging it is not calling the bean method.

HomePage.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <ui:composition>
        <h:form>

            <h:panelGrid columns="4" width="100%">

                <h:commandLink action="#{home.showPage}" value="Home">
                    <f:param name="pageName" value="home" />
                    <f:ajax event="action" render="pgdb"/>
                </h:commandLink>
                <h:commandLink action="#{home.showPage}"
                               value="DashBoard">
                    <f:param name="pageName" value="dashBoard" />
                    <f:ajax event="action" render="pgdb"/>
                </h:commandLink>

            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:panelGroup id="pgdb" rendered="#{home.showDashBoard}">
                <ui:include src="/DashBoard.xhtml"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:form>
    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

DashBoard.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <table border="1" width="30%">
                <tr>
                    <h:commandLink action="#{dashBoard.showPage}"
                                   value="Add Field">
                        <f:param name="pageName" value="addField" />
                    </h:commandLink>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </h:panelGrid>
        <ui:include src="AddField.xhtml"/>
    </h:form>
</html>
```

AddField.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <ui:composition>
        <h:form>
            <h:outputText value=FirstName" />
            <h:outputText value="LastName" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

home.java

```
package ims.com.home;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@ManagedBean(name="home")
@Scope
@Component
public class Home implements Serializable {

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.pageName}")
    private String pageName;

    private boolean showDashBoard = false;

    public boolean isShowDashBoard() {
        return showDashBoard;
    }

    public void setShowDashBoard(boolean showDashBoard) {
        this.showDashBoard = showDashBoard;
    }

    public String showPage() {
        if (pageName == "home") {
            showDashBoard = false;
            return "HomePage";
        }

        if (pageName.equals("dashBoard")) {
            showDashBoard = true;
            return "HomePage";
        }
    }

    public String getPageName() {
        return pageName;
    }

    public void setPageName(String pageName) {
        this.pageName = pageName;
    }
}
```

dashBoard.java

```
package ims.com.dashboard;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;


@ManagedBean(name="dashBoard")
@ViewScoped
public class DashBoard implements Serializable {

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.pageName}")
    private String pageName;

    public String showPage() {
        if (pageName == "addField") {
            return "AddField";
        }
    }

    public void setPageName(String pageName) {
        this.pageName = pageName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some code, and I will have a look.

Comment: Why do you add that much code which is irrelevant to the actual  problem domain? Please consider making it a shortest piece of code that identifies/reproduces the same problem to get better help sooner.

Comment: I have removed some line of code..

Comment: Some obvious things : You are comparing Strings with `==` (`pageName == "home"`) in the `showPage()` method of the `Home` class which needs a comparison by means of the `equals()` method. There is a missing `return` statement in the same method - `showPage()`. The same thing is being repeated in the `DashBoard` class - comparing Strings with `==` (`pageName == "addField"`) and a missing `return` statement.